# Assigning a static IP to a Windows 8.1 Pro Hyper-V host

Tags: networking, hyper-v, host

I have a Windows 8.1 Hyper-V host.
It has 2 interfaces.  One interface is dedicated to hyperv vms (uses physical device "Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #4)
The other interface (Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #2) is for accessing the host itself.

My problem is that since adding Hyper-V, I cannot assign a static IP address to Ethernet #2.  DHCP works fine.  When I attempt to assign a static IP by editing the IPv4 properties of Ethernet #2, the interface keeps getting an APIPA IP instead of the one I assigned.

Hyper-V bug?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you create a Hyper-V virtual switch bound to Ethernet #2? If so, you don't need to do that.

Comment: Nope, there is a virtual switch, but it uses Ethernet #4.  It is connected to "external network" and does not have "Allow management operating system to share .." checked.